# How can I make a Python program executable so that it automatically runs

Tags: python, programming-languages

I have a very basic Python program which alarms you at certain intervals for break...I want to make it a software so that I don't need to run that program everytime I open my computer ...and I want it for both windows and Linux....And is there universal way to create executable files from source code in any language

Comment: You can try using the Control M scheduling tool.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to make python code executable, or how to automatically start the python code when you log in, or both?

Comment: Actually both..

Answer (score 1):

**For Linux**, you can specify your .py(script) file and then have a cron job to run it based on your setup. You can schedule script to be executed periodically.
Your cron job script can be edited as: 
Opens crontab edit:

```
# crontab -e
```

And add following entry if you want a scheduled job:

```
0 6 * * * /usr/bin/python your_script.py
```

So this will run every day at 6 am. For more options refer to http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Or if you want to add it to run at startup add the following entry:

```
@reboot  /usr/bin/python your_script.py &
```

---

**For Windows** create a batch job and append it to your startup schedule, so this will run whenever you boot up your system.

1. batch file can be like(given you have a installed python version in your system):

   ```
   @echo off
   python your_script.py
   PAUSE
   ```
2. save it as some_name.bat
3. Create a shortcut of the file in startup folder(which can be opened using RUN > shell:startup)
4. Paste your batch file shortcut in above location.
5. For scheduled run for python script in windows refer to https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/analytics/scheduling-a-python-script-or-model-to-run-at-a-prescribed-time/